# pd.Dataframe has data in its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas Dataframe `df` with the following structure:

```
                                         wind speed
longitude   latitude time                          
-213.12     15.66    1987-10-18 12:00:00  24.259371
            15.41    1987-10-18 12:00:00  23.964531
            15.16    1987-10-18 12:00:00  22.634521
            ...
 504.88     14.66    1987-10-18 12:00:00  18.307228
            14.41    1987-10-18 12:00:00  16.786293
            14.16    1987-10-18 12:00:00  17.327431
```

That is, the only keyed column is wind speed, and the lon, lat, time variables are part of `df.index`, which looks like this:

```
MultiIndex([(-213.12, 15.66, '1987-10-18 12:00:00'),
            (-213.12, 15.41, '1987-10-18 12:00:00'),
            (-213.12, 15.16, '1987-10-18 12:00:00'),
            ...
            (504.88, 14.66, '1987-10-18 12:00:00'),
            (504.88, 14.41, '1987-10-18 12:00:00'),
            (504.88, 14.16, '1987-10-18 12:00:00')])
```

I'd like to restructure `df` into a dataframe with columns for lon, lat, and time as well as wind speed, ideally without looping over `df.index`. What is the most computationally efficient way to do this?

Comment: `df = df.reset_index()`?

Comment: Yup. Easy fix, thanks